# CSS - I don't want the "transition" value set to the parent effect its children

Tags: html, css, css-animations, parent-child

I have a wrapper that holds my content divs
I need the wrapper to animate left and hide with its children (this happens one time if the user submit a form).
The children's font size etc is set according to `rem` value.

**Issue:** when viewport resize the font size animate when `rem` size change

HTML SMAPLE

```
<div class="frame">
  <div class="wrap">
    <p>Sample Title For Test</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS SAMPLE

```
.frame{overflow:hidden}
.wrap{transition:1s ease}
p{font-size:1rem}

@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
 html {
  font-size: 12px;
 }
}
```

on the real page, I have a lot of children I need to tell them all to not inherit the transition from the parent, how can I do this?

Comment: insert more code pls

Comment: Since you're changing `left` property of `.wrap`, try `.wrap{transition: left 1s ease}`

Comment: Perfect !! I don't know how I haven't thought about this approach, I actually use `transform` - Thank you!